# I styled checkboxes with labels, but my JavaScript doesn't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

So I have styled checkboxes with CSS and a sprite using this markup:

```
<div class="open-checkbox">
   <label class="open-checkbox">
      <input id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="key-areas-checkbox" name="interests[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $label; ?>" />
   </label>
</div>
```

and this JS:

```
$(".key-areas-checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    $(this).next().addClass('checked');
});

$('.open-checkbox').click(function () {
    console.log('click');
    var $this = $(this);
    var $input = $this.find('input');

    $this.toggleClass('checked', $input.is(':checked'));
    return;

    if($input.prop('checked')){
        $this.removeClass('checked');
    } else {
        $this.addClass('checked');
    }
});
```

And this works in all browsers except IE8 and IE7.  Does anyone know how to make this work in those browsers? FYI - the inputs are hidden.  I noticed that if I made visibility:visible, checked the checkbox, then hid it again, it displays properly.

Comment: There's no console in IE7 and IE8, if you take it out, does it effect the code?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". Do you see any errors? Check your browser console. BTW, that's doomed to fail on IE if you don't have the dev tools open, due to the console.log line.

Comment: after the `return;` your code is not reachable for it exits the function. And what should this line do: `$this.toggleClass('checked', $input.is(':checked'));` ? Toggle class "checked" with "(boolean)" ?

Comment: I don't see any errors, and when I say 'doesn't work' - I mean it doesn't show the 'checked' class when the inputs are styled as visibility:hidden

Comment: @Christo did you try without the console.log as Victor suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is a really bad idea:

```
<div class="      open-checkbox  ">
   <label class=" open-checkbox  ">
```

than:

```
$(".key-areas-checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    $(this).next().addClass('checked'); // next? you have no next element!
});
```

Also:

```
return; // Exit function and...

// ...forget about this code.
if($input.prop('checked')){
    $this.removeClass('checked');
} else {
    $this.addClass('checked');
}
```

I would do:

```
$('.open-checkbox-label').click(function( e ) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    var $lab = $(this);   
    $lab.toggleClass('checked');
    // not sure what are you trying to do here with inputs...

});
```

<sub>No need to say: Note the new class for your LABEL element. Additionally you need to be careful with browser support of console.log, there are plenty of answers on SO regardin how to fix that.</sub>

Comment: @Christo I just give you some suggestions + fixes, cause I have no idea what are you trying to do. A demo fiddle would be really useful

Comment: NAILED IT!  Thanks Roko!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Could you figure out how it 'worked' in all other browsers ?

Comment: @MilchePatern removing the console.log and with all the other small stuff.